# Android Notification on Launcher Icon

Tags: android, notifications, icons, launcher

There are some android apps (such as the native email app) that show iPhone like notifications on the launcher icon.  This is the launcher icon, not the shortcut on the home screen.

Does anyone know how this is done?

I would like to show notifications on the launcher icon as well as in the status bar.

I do not find any information how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know how this is done?

It is a custom feature of your device's home screen, presumably. For example, the "native email app" does not "show iPhone like notifications on the launcher icon" on most devices.

Comment: Indeed this is a native feature of the phone.  Guess we have to wait for a future update of the SDK... maybe?

Comment: @bob_and_ted: Possibly, but it'd be a non-trivial change. Typically, they steer you towards app widgets, so dynamically-changing things are on the home screen directly rather than in the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of an API to do this. Maybe this is a firmware modification of the phone you are using. I have never seen Apps that are able to add a badge to their app icon in the launcher.

On what kind of device have you found this apps?

Comment: I have a samsung galaxy S.  Both the native mail app and the Samsung App have this little iPhone like notifications.  I could well be this is some kind of native OS hack performed by Samsung, and thus not possible by "normal" means.

Comment: I checked this with a Galaxy Tab 7" and I see what you mean. As I and CommonsWare said this is a feature of the Samsung launcher that is as far as I found information is not usable by third party developers.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen widgets that emulate badges and are iconic in size.